# how to handle packets in multi-threaded server client program?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winsock, client-server

I currently have a client app that works but it is single threaded.

my packets look like this: < len_of_data>|< data>"

"|" is used as a separator for my data.

< len_of_data> is always 4 digits long followed.

< data> looks like: |< transaction id>|< command>|< buflen>|< buf>|< checksum>|

my code to create the packets is:

```
_snprintf_s(data_buffer, WS_MAX_DATA_PACKET_SIZE, 
               WS_MAX_DATA_PACKET_SIZE - 1,
               "%s%d%s%d%s%d%s%s%s%d%s", 
               WS_PACKET_SEP, pkt->transaction_id, 
               WS_PACKET_SEP, pkt->command, 
               WS_PACKET_SEP, pkt->bufsize, 
               WS_PACKET_SEP, pkt->buf, 
               WS_PACKET_SEP, pkt->checksum, WS_PACKET_SEP);

buf_len = strlen(data_buffer);

_snprintf_s(send_buffer, WS_MAX_DATA_PACKET_SIZE, 
            WS_MAX_DATA_PACKET_SIZE - 1, "%04d%s%s", 
            buf_len, WS_PACKET_SEP, data_buffer);

buf_len = strlen(send_buffer);
// Send buffer
bytes_sent = send(ConnectSocket, send_buffer, buf_len, 0);
```

The client thread sends a command to the server, then calls a GetIncomingPackets() function.  In GetIncomingPackets(), I call recv() to get 5 bytes, this should be the len of the rest of packet, I parse these 5 bytes and verify that they match my expected format.  Then I convert the first 4 bytes to an integer, x.  Then I call recv() again to get x bytes more and then parse those out into my packet structure.

The problem happens when I add another thread to do the same thing (send and receive commands).
I start my app and fire 2 threads and send them to send different commands and wait for responses.  When the threads call GetIncomingPackets(), the data I am getting back is invalid.  The first 5 bytes I am expecting are missing sometimes, and I just get the following 5 bytes, therefore I am unable to get my < len_of_data > packet.

I even added a critical section block between the 2 recv() calls in my GetIncomingPackets() so the treads dont interrupt each other while getting a full packet.
Without some extra code for error checking, this how the function looks like

```
#define WS_SIZE_OF_LEN_PACKET 5
bool GetIncomingPackets(SOCKET sd, dev_sim_packet_t *pkt )
{
    char len_str_buf[WS_SIZE_OF_LEN_PACKET + 1] = {0};      // + 1 for NULL char
    char data_buf[WS_MAX_DATA_PACKET_SIZE + 1] = {0};
    int ret = 0;
    int data_len = 0;

    EnterCriticalSection( &recv_critical_section );
    nReadBytes = WS_RecvAll(sd, len_str_buf, WS_SIZE_OF_LEN_PACKET );
    ret = WS_VerifyLenPacket(len_str_buf);
    // Convert data packet lenght string received to int 
    data_len = WS_ConvertNumberFromString(len_str_buf, WS_SIZE_OF_LEN_PACKET );   
    // Get data from packet
    nReadBytes = WS_RecvAll(sd, data_buf, data_len);
    LeaveCriticalSection( &recv_critical_section  );
    ret = ParseMessager(data_buf, data_len, pkt);
}
```

My question is, what could be causing this problem, and how could I fix it?  Or is there better ways to do what i am trying to do.  The reason that I'm trying to make it multi-threaded is because my app will communicate with 2 other sources, and I want to have a thread to handle each request that comes in from either source.

thanks in advance and feel free to ask any questions if I didn't explain something well.

Here's the code for WS_RecvAll().  The buffer is a static buffer declared in GetIncomingPackets() like this:

```
  char data_buf[WS_MAX_DATA_PACKET_SIZE + 1] = {0};   // + 1 for NULL char


int WS_RecvAll(SOCKET socket_handle, char* buffer, int size)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int read = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char err_buf[100] = {0};
    while(size)
    {
        ret = recv(socket_handle, &buffer[read], size, 0);
        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("***ERROR***: recv failed, error = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return WS_ERROR_RECV_FAILED;
        }
        if (ret == 0) {
            break;
        }
        read += ret;
        size -= ret;
     }
     return read;
 }
```

Comment: What is the protocol in use between the client and the server? (i.e. TCP or UDP?)

Comment: Post the code for WS_RecvAll.

Comment: How does WS_RecvAll allocate the data_buf?

Comment: I posted teh code  WS_RecvAll as part of the question now.

Comment: In you _snprintf_s statement above, you are formatting the message out with %s formatters.  But if pkt->buf is binary data, then any data past the first nul byte will get truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to debug MT problems, particularly at one remove, but if you are using  astatic buffer, should not:

```
 LeaveCriticalSection( &recv_critical_section  );
 ret = ParseMessager(data_buf, data_len, pkt);
```

be:

```
 ret = ParseMessager(data_buf, data_len, pkt);
 LeaveCriticalSection( &recv_critical_section  );
```

And why use a static buffer in any case?

Comment: ok, it's not declared static.  what i meant was, that i am not allocating it using malloc.  I am using a buffer of constant size to receive my data since I always know what the max data that I can receive is.  Does that make sense? or do u think I should allocate the buffer dynamically everytime anyway?

Comment: @emge That makes sense. Don't add dynamic allocation to your woes. I would still try moving the LeaveCriticalSection call, however.

Comment: @emge actually, I just re-read your code, and unless I miss something you ARE allocating the buffer statically - i.e. not within a function.

Comment: well I am not sure what you think I should do? I am not using the key word static anywhere.

Comment: @emge anything defined outside of  a function is static. Move the buffer definition inside the function, or move the LCS call.

Comment: I've already moved the LCS call after ParseMessage().  And I have the buffer definition inside the GetIncomingPackets() already. Are u saying it should be in another function?

Comment: @emge Nope, that is OK. Other than that, your code looks OK to me, but spotting MT errors is REALLY hard. I had an MT server at an investment bank I was working for that had a bug (written be me) that took me a couple of months to track down, but was obvious when I actually spotted it. So don't feel too bad! Sorry not be more help.

Comment: well thanks for your input, I'll try to figure out what is what causing the problem.

Comment: it seems that the 2nd thread is entering the critical section when the first thread is not done getting the 2nd part of the packet.  Why would that be?  Sometimes the CS works and sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: @emge I find that highly unlikely. The error is almost certainly somewhere in your own code, and possibly nothing to do with threading. But I guess you could try replacing the CS with a mutex.

Comment: I found the error.  I was calling InitializeCriticalSection() twice, once for each thread, instead of calling it once in main before i created the threads.  It seems to be working as expected now.

Comment: The only problem I have now is that, each threads expects a response, and sometimes about 0.1% of the time, the server responds to the threads out of order.  So thread A sends transaction 1, thread B sends transaction 2, then server responds to transactions, and thread A gets response to transaction 2, and thread B gets respoonse to transaction 1.  whats a good solution for this?

Comment: @emge Congrats on finding the bug. You can't assume anything about thread scheduling, so your code will have to be able to cope with responses in any order.

Answer (score 0):

Im curious to know whether you have used the same socked descriptor in both the threads to connect to the server.